# Amazon AWS - many accounts in same app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have the following code:

```
...
var  AWS_Stg = require('aws-sdk'),
     AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS_Stg.config.update({ accessKeyId: '1ª Account', secretAccessKey: '1ª Account' });
AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: '2ª Account', secretAccessKey: '2ª Account' });
...
```

But can only access one of the accounts.
How to access more than one account in the same app (node.js)?

Comment: What language is this? Can you please label your question accordingly? Thanks!

Comment: Node.js. Sorry, tag was removed.

Answer (score 0):

When making a call to AWS, use either `AWS_Stg` or `AWS`.

For example:

```
var s3 = new AWS_Stg.S3();
var params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myImageFile.jpg'};
var file = require('fs').createWriteStream('/path/to/file.jpg');
s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(file);
```

When creating the S3 client object, use either `var s3 = new AWS_Stg.S3();` or `var s3 = new AWS_Stg.S3();`